# Would a Amazon EC2 T2 instance be suitable to run TensorFlow Mobile or TensorFlow Lite?

Tags: swift, tensorflow, amazon-ec2

I'm learning about Amazon web services for mobile and I do have a project in mind.   I don't think I plan on creating machine learning data models from scratch however I did notice there is a AI/machine learning service within AWS.  I plan on using CoreML for iOS.  I'm currently learning from the free tier and I wonder how much will truly be offered in this option.  I'd like to know if a T2 instance is suitable enough to work with TensorFlow Mobile or TensorFlow Lite?

Comment: Do you have TensorFlow model available/downloaded. There are tools to convert them from TensorFlow models to CoreML. It will help to do ml calculations locally.

Comment: I have documentation on where I can find available models such as on ImageNet however I didn't know if the machine learning service within AWS is something I should even be thinking about?  I've read its best to do ml calculations locally as you've stated so I may be over thinking my project as I learn about the options available on AWS.

Comment: Which type of model you want, ImageNet and around 4-5 more models are already available in CoreML. You can also find models on Kaggle site.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TensorFlow Mobile or TensorFlow Lite, still need to know what kind of process you are going to perform.

If you are going to build a model using T2 instances then I recommend going with P2 instances.

If you are going to run a mode using T2 instances then you can try on t2.2xlarge
But it won't be smooth and that much accurate as compare to GPU performance
But if your use-case is not that much deep n critical then this will definitely help you with performance and cost saving